# How can I update data in related entities (Symfony)?

Tags: symfony, oop, doctrine, associations, entity

This is an extract of my entity `Cats`:

```
   ....

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Dogs")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="type", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  private $type;

  public function getType(): ?Dogs
  {
    return $this->type;
  }

 public function setType(?Dogs $type): self
      {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
      }
```

And this of entity `Dogs`:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25)
     */
    private $name;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }
```

Right now the `type` is set to "2":

```
2 => Cats {#6214 ▼
    -id: 3
    -name: "password"
    -type: Dogs {#6211 ▼
      +__isInitialized__: true
      -id: 2
      -name: "hidden"
      -label: "hidden"
       …2
     …2}
  }
```

I want to update it to "3":

```
$entity->setType(2);
$em->flush();
```

But I get the error message:

> Argument 1 passed to App\Entity\Cats::setType() must be an instance
>   of App\Entity\Dogs or null, string given, called in
>   /Users/work/project/src/Controller/PagesController.php on line 242

How can I create an instance of entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually since you got the id of the related entity you don't need to fully load the entity from the database, you can just pass a reference to this entity. It's faster and doesn't add unnecessary overhead to your code:

```
$dogId = 3;
$dog = $em->getReference(Dogs::class, $dogId);
$entity->setType($dog);
$em->flush();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not set the type to the id of a dog entity but to the entity directly. You need to do something like this:

```
$dog = $em->getRepository(Dog::class)->findOneById(2);
$entity->setType($dog);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: `getReference`  is working instead of `getRepository`

Comment: You probably meant findOneById(2); instead of get.

There's no big difference between getting reference or actual object in current case.